# Send Bytes From .net desktop application to website

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, web, byte

Is there any way  to send data (string , files ,,,) In the form of bytes from desktop application to website

Comment: Yes there is. Are you planning to use any specific programmig language for the application? What platform would you use for the web site?

Comment: yes c# ,,, and for website asp

Comment: The answer to the question you asked is "Yes, there is". Please see the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for guidance on how to ask a question that will generate a more in depth answer. Please also read the article on at http://www.WhatHaveYouTried.com, it only takes about 8 min to read and it gives a very good advice on how to ask a good question on this site that will generate good answers.

Comment: can u give exemple ? or Or what will use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`WebClient` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to send data in an HTTP request. A string; example:

```
string url = "http://website.com/MyController/MyAction";
string data = "Something";
string response;
using WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
  client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
  response = client.UploadString(url, data);
}
```

Or a byte array; example:

```
string url = "http://website.com/MyController/MyAction";
byte[] data = { 1, 2, 3 };
byte[] response;
using WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
  response = client.UploadData(url, data);
}
```

In the web application (assuming that you are using MVC and C#) you would have an action method in a controller that gets the data. Example:

```
public ActionResult MyAction() {
  byte[] data = Request.BinaryRead(Request.ContentLength);
  // do something with the data
  // create a byte array "response" with something to send back
  return Content(response, "text/plain");
}
```

Both a string and a byte array ends up as a byte array when sent, so you would use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data)` to turn the data into the string sent by `UploadString`.

To return a string for `UploadString` you would use `Encoding.GetBytes(str)` to turn a string into bytes.

There are several overloads of those methods that do similar things, that might fit your needs better, but this should get you started.

Comment: Is there any Other  Way ?

Comment: @Abdelhak: There are plenty of other ways, but most involve more complicated ways to communicate the data, or sends the data wrapped in some data structure (like for example multipart/formdata or XML). Is there any specific feature that you wanted to be different?

Comment: yes a wan't to connected  my desktop app with my website and send / receive data with Fastest way , Between Two Desktops Application I've been using socket/tcpclient but Between desktop app and website I did not know the best way ,,,,, and i'm sorry Sorry about my language, it's bad

Comment: @Abdelhak: The above code gives a minimum of overhead for a reasonable amount of code. You can get slightly less, but then it gets a lot more complicted. You can use the asynchronous counterparts of the methods in the `WebClient` class if you want the application to be more responsive, i.e. doesn't freeze when it's waiting for the response.

Comment: Thank you, but is not there some way, such as tcpclient between 2 desktop app ,, because i think this method Communication will be very slow

Comment: @Abdelhak: That's not how a web site communicates. It uses server-client calls in the form of HTTP messages. You could start a background thread in the site and use a TCP connection to communicate with a desktop application, but that's not a very stable solution. The web server periodically recycles the site, which would kill the background thread. The web server also may shut the site down to save resources when there are no incoming requests, with the same effect. A web site simply isn't supposed to run continuously.